# Count Color Changes In Excel Row

Tags: vba, excel, colors, count

I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of project hours.  Each project is assigned a color.  A row contains half hour increments.  Each half hour gets assigned a color based on which project is being worked on during that time.

I want to count the number of changes from one color to another for the length of the row.  A row is one day.

How can I do this in Excel?

Below is what a row looks like.  Each row is one day.  I need to count how many times the color changed in this row left to right.  So the output in this case would be 7 because the project changed 7 times.

[image]

Comment: Could you please put an example of the input data and the output you wish to obtain? Also, are the colors done with conditional formatting rules or not?

Comment: added an example row input with expected output.

Comment: I recommend adding vba tag as there's not other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly more condensed UDF:

```
Function CountColorChanges(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With rng.Columns
        If .Count > 1 Then
            For i = 1 To .Count - 1
                If rng.Cells(1, i + 1).Interior.Color <> rng.Cells(1, i).Interior.Color Then CountColorChanges = CountColorChanges + 1
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Function NumberOfColorChanges(ByVal rng As range)as long
    Dim cell As range
    Dim color As Long
    Dim firstCell As Boolean
    firstCell = True
    For Each cell In rng
        If firstCell = True Then
            color = cell.Interior.color
            firstCell = False
        Else
            If color <> cell.Interior.color Then
                NumberOfColorChanges = NumberOfColorChanges + 1
                color = cell.Interior.color
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```